# Python-Eve MongoDB Aggregation with ISODate

Tags: mongodb, flask, eve

i am trying to use an aggregation where in the $match condition is a date $GTE my given date.

schema:

```
hashtag_top = {
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'collection',
        'aggregation': {
            'pipeline': [
                { "$match": { "_updated": { "$gte" : "$upd" } } },
                { "$group": { "_id": '$Hashtag', "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
                { "$sort": { "count": -1 }},
                { "$limit": 10 }
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

= no result

```
hashtag_top = {
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'collection',
        'aggregation': {
            'pipeline': [
                { "$match": { "_updated": { "$gte" : ISODate("$upd") } } },
                { "$group": { "_id": '$Hashtag', "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
                { "$sort": { "count": -1 }},
                { "$limit": 10 }
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

= gives a dump when starting my run.py

EDIT
Request:

```
http://myserver:5000/hashtag_top/?aggregate={"$upd": "+myjsisodate+"}
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of your request?

Comment: Hi nicola, yes sure it looks something like: myserver:5000/hashtag_top/?aggregate={"$upd": "+myjsisodate+"}

Comment: is there maybe a way to provide this field using flask? (my python is a little bit bad :-) i just want to get documents with this aggregation where _updated timestamp > (now-3days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo aggregation framework support for Eve has not been released yet, so I assume  you are on the development branch. Currently, dates are not parsed. I opened a [ticket](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/issues/858) for this, which will be addressed before 0.7 (with Aggregation Framework support) is released.

UPDATE: date processing is now supported on Eve 0.7-dev. Just make sure you provide a date in RFC 1123 (ex RFC 822) format:

```
http://myserver:5000/hashtag_top/?aggregate={"$upd": "Mon, 9 May 2016 12:00:00 GMT"}
```

Comment: @HaraldWiesinger I updated the answer as date parsing is now supported. If it works for  you now, please accept the answer.

Comment: hey cool, thank you! i will try this later in the evening ;-)

Comment: Is there a reason,  why not to give the date as an isodate?

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thank you for the fast support :)